# creating an object doesn't work

Tags: python, object, typeerror

```
class phonebook:
    def __init__(self,first_name, last_name, street, postcode, city, number):

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title('Book')

        menubar = tk.Menu(root)
        root.config(menu = menubar)
        menubar.add_command(label = 'Anlegen', command = self.create)
        menubar.add_command(label = 'Bearbeiten', command = self.change)
        menubar.add_command(label = 'Löschen')
        menubar.add_command(label = 'Sortieren')
        menubar.add_command(label = 'Suche')
        menubar.add_command(label = 'Hilfe')

        root.mainloop()

    def printing(self):
        account = (self.first_name.get(), self.last_name.get(), self.street.get(), self.postcode.get(), self.city.get(), self.number.get())
        accounts.append(account)
        for i in accounts:
            print(i)
    def change(self):
        account = accounts[0]
        account.first_name = 'test'
        self.printing

    def create(self):

        creation = tk.Toplevel()

        tk.Label(creation, text = 'Vorname').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        tk.Label(creation, text = 'Nachname').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        tk.Label(creation, text = 'Stadt').grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        tk.Label(creation, text = 'Postleitzahl').grid(row = 4, column = 0)
        tk.Label(creation, text = 'Straße').grid(row = 5, column = 0)
        tk.Label(creation, text = 'Telefonnummer').grid(row = 6, column = 0)


        self.first_name = tk.Entry(creation)
        self.last_name = tk.Entry(creation)
        self.city = tk.Entry(creation)
        self.postcode = tk.Entry(creation)
        self.street = tk.Entry(creation)
        self.number = tk.Entry(creation)

        a = tk.Button(creation, text = 'end', command = self.printing)

        self.first_name.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.last_name.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.city.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        self.postcode.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        self.street.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
        self.number.grid(row = 6, column = 1)
        a.grid(row = 7, column = 1)

phonebook()
```

As you can see in my code I'm trying to create and edit objects. The problem is that I cannot create a real object. When I want to create a object with class `phonebook`, I get this error:

> TypeError: `__init__()` missing 6 required positional arguments: 'first_name', 'last_name', 'street', 'postcode', 'city', and 'number'

What do I have to do so that I don't get this error and so that I can edit the objects?

Comment: You have a call to `phonebook()`...and as you can see, that call doesn't have any args, even though your `__init__` expects 6 args. So it breaks. Nice username

Answer (score 0):

`phonebook` must be called with 6 arguments, not 0. You call `phonebook()`, which causes your code to break. Try calling with something like this:

```
phonebook("first_name", "last_name", "street", "post_code", "your_city", 123)
```

substitute in the appropriate values instead of the ones I've provided.

P.S. You won't get much help on this site with a username like that